# How to add --no-sound-null-safety on a single run/debug on vscode (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

On vscode, when try run or debug using "Run" or "Debug" button, the runner doesn't add --no-sound-null-safety argument.

How to configure vscode to add --no-sound-null-safety argument?

[image]

[image]

Comment: related: this option is not a thing anymore in Dart 3.0 https://stackoverflow.com/q/76238071/11107541

Answer (score 8):

If using vscode. create .vscode/launch.json in project root and add

```
"args": [
     "--no-sound-null-safety"
    ]
```

complete code :-

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
            {
                    "name": "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME",
                    "program": "lib/main.dart",
                    "request": "launch",
                    "type": "dart",
                    "args": [
                            "--no-sound-null-safety"
                        ]
            }
    ]
```

}`

Comment: Sorry, but it only works when I run all tests and not a specific test. Take a look the print screen, I would like debug using "Run" or "Debug" button inside the code.

Comment: This worked for me as far as running the project and also being able to attached a device to VSCode. I'll deal with null safety when the the http and http_parser libs have been updated.

Answer (score 6):

follow these instruction 
Goto:

```
File -> Preferences -> Settings
```

Then search:

```
Flutter run additional args
```

Then Add new arg like this

```
--no-sound-null-safety
```

**Then simply run**
***Also can follow image***
[image: Go here]

then do this
[image]

Answer (score 5):

**For IDE run arguments/configuration**

Search for "Flutter run additional args"
in your user settings and add `--no-sound-null-safety` .
Paste the command in the item field and click ok as we already added one command.

[image]

**For Test configuration**

Search for "Flutter test additional args" in your user settings and add `--no-sound-null-safety` . Do the same process as on the above picture and add this command.

after all, you will be able to run unsound null or hybrid apps with debug button

Answer (score 4):

I added these items to the settings.json file.

```json
{
    "dart.flutterTestAdditionalArgs": ["--no-sound-null-safety"],
    "dart.flutterAdditionalArgs": ["--no-sound-null-safety"],
    "dart.vmAdditionalArgs": ["--no-sound-null-safety"]
}
```