# After Flutter 3.10 and Dart 3.0 upgrade VS Code unable to run tests with error: Could not find an option named "no-sound-null-safety"

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I have just updated to Flutter 3.10 and Dart 3.0 and followed the Dart 3.0 migration steps shown [here](https://dart.dev/resources/dart-3-migration) and running "dart analyze" shows no errors.
However when I ask VS Code to run my tests all I get is:

> Could not find an option named "no-sound-null-safety".
>
> Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter  -h') for available flutter commands and options.
>
> Exited (1)

I have updated Dart Code to v3.64.0 in VS Code but I still get the same error.

If I run "flutter test" in the VS Code terminal the tests all run as expected.

Any idea how I can get the tests running in VS Code again?

Answer (score 2):

As of Dart 3.0, sound null safety is required, and this option no longer exists. In your `settings.json` for the workspace & user, find & remove the `"--no-sound-null-safety"` argument in the `"dart.flutterAdditionalArgs"` setting.

You may also search for the `Flutter Additional Args` section of the settings and remove there.

If you are not yet ready to run with sound null safety, your only option is to downgrade Dart/Flutter. `flutter downgrade`

Answer (score 0):

And for Android Studio, goto : Run --> Edit Configurations. Remove "--no-sound-null-safety" from Additional run args

Answer (score 0):

When I migrated my Flutter project to Flutter 3.10 and I got an error when I tried to run the app.

Error

````html
ERROR:  - 'TapUpDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart' ('/opt/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap.dart').
ERROR:  - 'TapDragUpDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('/opt/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
ERROR: Change to a supertype of 'TapDragUpDetails', or, for a covariant parameter, a subtype.
ERROR:   void onSingleTapUp(TapUpDetails details) {
ERROR:                                   ^
ERROR: /opt/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text_selection.dart:2161:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('onSingleTapUp').
ERROR:   void onSingleTapUp(TapDragUpDetails details) {
ERROR:        ^
ERROR: ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/macos_ui-1.12.2/lib/src/fields/text_field.dart:130:42: Error: The parameter 'details' of the method '_TextFieldSelectionGestureDetectorBuilder.onDragSelectionEnd' has type 'DragEndDetails', which does not match the corresponding type, 'TapDragEndDetails', in the overridden method, 'TextSelectionGestureDetectorBuilder.onDragSelectionEnd'.
ERROR:  - 'DragEndDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('/opt/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
ERROR:  - 'TapDragEndDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('/opt/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
ERROR: Change to a supertype of 'TapDragEndDetails', or, for a covariant parameter, a subtype.
ERROR:   void onDragSelectionEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
ERROR:                                          ^
ERROR: /opt/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text_selection.dart:2839:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('onDragSelectionEnd').
ERROR:   void onDragSelectionEnd(TapDragEndDetails details) {
ERROR:        ^
ERROR: Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
Exception: Build process failed```
````

After that i used thad trip its work for me

```html
dependency_overrides:
  macos_ui:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/Mayb3Nots/macos_ui.git
      ref: dev
```