# App Running in android studio but showing error in VS code

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, mobile, mobile-application

Could not find an option named "no-sound-null-safety".

Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter  -h') for available flutter commands and options.

Exited (1)

My Flutter version 3.10.6 &Dart version 3.0.6

Expecting to run in vs code

Comment: did you add no-sound-null-safety flag to your Flutter or Dart commands?

Comment: Probably at one point you added it in VS code like it's done in the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67904982/how-to-add-no-sound-null-safety-on-a-single-run-debug-on-vscode-flutter . The latest version of Flutter doesn't allow no-sound-null-safety anymore so you need to remove it again.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem before.i think you should downgrade flutter version with your app compatible version. can be 3.7.12

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

From `flutter version 3.10.6` `--no-sound-null-safety` tag was removed

And this can not be used to run the project.

You have to make your project null safe to run the project using `flutter run`

Remove all the dependencies which do not support `null safety` or use their `null safe` version.

And then run `flutter clean` -> `flutter pub get` -> `flutter run`

This will successfully run your project.